# Unexpected behaviour while running recursion func over slice

Tags: go, recursion, slice

In Python, I can do recursion such as:

```py
def dfs(a, path):
    if len(a) == 0:
        print(path)
        return
    for i in range(len(a)):
        dfs(a[:i]+a[i+1:], path+str(a[i]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = [10, 2]
    dfs(a, "")
```

It will output:

```
102
210
```

However, if I do a similar thing in Go,

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func dfs(ns []int, path string) {
    if len(ns) == 0 {
        fmt.Println(path)
        return
    }

    for i, v := range ns {
        nx := append(ns[:i], ns[i+1:]...)
        dfs(nx, fmt.Sprintf("%v%v", path, v))
    }
}

func main() {
    nums := []int{10, 2}
    dfs(nums, "")
}
```

The output would be:

```
102
22
```

I guess this behavior is due to the slice linking to underline array on Go, but I don't understand how, and how to debug this.

Can you please point me out the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code modifies the backing array of ns:

```
    nx := append(ns[:i], ns[i+1:]...)
```

Fix by [copying the slice elements](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks#copy) to a new backing array:

```
    nx := append(([]int)(nil), ns[:i]...) // copy
    nx = append(nx, ns[i+1:]...)
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/OBgchimucWJ).

You can also force a copy by using a [full slice expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions):

```
    nx := append(ns[0:i:i], ns[i+1:]...)
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mP5U3pyoZJy).

Comment: thanks for the answer. It helped a lot. A follow up question, I tried doing these after saw your answer, `nx := []int{}; copy(nx, ns[0:i]);nx = append(nx, ns[i+1:]...)` however, the result is still a bit off. Can you please let me know, why the back array is modified with the copy.  https://play.golang.org/p/q6nPQBPhK7k

Comment: The built-in `copy` function does not extend the slice.  The statement `copy(nx, ns[0:i])` copies zero elements to `nx` because `nx` has length zero.  See [slice tricks](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks#copy) for variations on copying a slice.

Comment: `Copy returns the number of elements copied, which will be the minimum of len(src) and len(dst).` Lesson learned. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @IanZhang  if it solved your question, you should mark it as resolved by checking the green tick on this answer. It is a nice way of thanking SOers for their help.